# Find the explicit path of %USERPROFILE% in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, python, virtualenv

I am trying to find the current %USERPROFILE% path on windows 7.

What is the simplest way to do this?

I've tried hunting around with `regedit`

---

N.b. I'm doing this as part of setting up a [python virtual envionment](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/200/hello-world/748/starting-a-project#t=201608091427077796337) [on windows](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/access-environment-variables-from-python help?

Comment: `echo %userprofile%` in a command prompt doesn't suffice?

Comment: @DudenamedBen Thanks yes - came to the same answer independently in the end..

Comment: I put it in, but you can accept it or your own answer.  Whatever floats your boat. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not looking for a python-specific answer, you can just open a command prompt and run `echo %userprofile%`.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it using python:

```
import os
os.environ['USERPROFILE']
```